# Compare objects with custom Matcher

Tags: java, junit, mockito, hamcrest

Hi I have two collections of objects to compare which are of different type but both has same properties. Example:
ObjA:

```
public class ObjA {
    private String aaa;
    private String bbb;
    private String ccc;
    private ObjX xxx;
    //getters and setters
}
```

and ObjB:

```
public class ObjB {
    private String aaa;
    private String bbb;
    private String ccc;
    private ObjX xxx;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Currently I compare its manualy, property by property. Do exist some more pretty solution for that? If not can you give me hint or example how to write custom Matcher for compare `List<ObjA>` and `List<objB>`? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I decide to write custom matcher which extends `TypeSafeMatcher<ObjA>` and when I compare String values, matcher decide are equals, but when I compare objects ObjX, it's mark as mismatch.
Code:

```
public class ObjAMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<ObjA> {
    Matcher<? super String> aaa;
    Matcher<? super String> bbb;
    Matcher<? super String> ccc;
    Matcher<? super ObjX> xxx;

    public ObjAMatcher(ObjB entity) {
        aaa = is(entity.getAaa());
        bbb = is(entity.getBbb());
        ccc = is(entity.getCcc());
        xxx = is(entity.getXxx());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(ObjB objB) {
        boolean equals = true;
        match &= aaa.matches(objB.getAaa()); // true
        match &= bbb.matches(objB.getBbb()); // true
        match &= ccc.matches(objB.getCcc()); // true
        match &= xxx.matches(objB.getXxx()); // false
        return match;
    }
    // ...
}
```

How to do xxx match too? I am sure ObjX's properties has same value in both objects.

Comment: Extract the common functionality (properties) to a base class then compare the Base.